# Очистка БД от ненужных записей

Tags: mysql

В общем, у меня есть папка с файлами, есть много записей БД с информацией об этих файлах, много файлов было удалено, и теперь стоит задача очистить БД от ненужных. Хотел сделать всё быстро и просто, однако очень странно, что у меня ничего не вышло.

Простой костыль, который мне не помог:

```
if ($open = scandir(FILES)) {
    foreach ($open as $k => $v) {
        if ($v != "." && $v != ".." && $v != "thumb") {
            $db->query("delete from `files` where `filename` != '{$v}'");
        }
    }
}
```

Что можно завелосипедить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Логика вашего кода в том, что вы находите файл в  директории и пытаетесь удалить все записи в БД, поле filename которых не равно имени файла? - так это то же самое, что написать запрос

```
delete from `files`
```

Вам надо пройтись по директории, собрать все имена файлов в массив и затем выполнить такой вот запрос:

```
 delete from `files` WHERE `filename` NOT IN ($files);
```

`$files` - список файлов в кавычках через запятую ('1.txt','2.txt' и т.д.).

Comment: Очень странно, что google не показал мне такую конструкцию запроса. Спасибо.